# System Centre - domain computers not listed automatically in computer Management ,Collections

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I am deploying System Centre Configuration Manager 2007 on the network.
The installation of SCCM was completed successfully. There were some additional steps like requesting and issuing certificates from the Domain Controller (acting as a Certificate Authority).
SCCM connects to a separate MSSQL Server to host it's database.

I am not sure if I should see all my domain computers 'automatically' in SCCM. I have played with the discover methods but that did not seem to work. I do not want to manually install 'CCMSetup' on each client.

Note that as part of setup, the domain PCs have a certificate signed by the CA for client authentication.

Comment: If you want SCCM to do the install you have to configure a discovery method (I'd highly recommend AD System discovery) and a Client Installation method. You could also push it out via GPO. I don't mean to be offputting, but SCCM is a massive management suite and you're failure bound if you don't read the friendly manual. MS has detailed step by step directions for this stuff, not following them is going to cause problems, lots of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Chris S said, you will need to configure a discovery method for the SCCM site server to collect all of the machines.  Active Directory System Discovery is a good place to start.  By default, this discovery method polls the selected container(s) once per day (but can be adjusted).  Once a machine is discovered, it will automatically populate within the appropriate queried collections (although an 'Update collection membership' may be required to refresh the collection).  Once the machine has been added to SCCM, you can automatically deploy the SCCM client agent to your machines via a software advertisement.

SCCM is extraordinarily complex.  If this is your first go at it, I would *highly* recommend either testing your setup in a lab environment or retain the services of an SCCM consultant prior to deploying on your real world system.  It is very easy to negatively impact your network if you configure SCCM improperly.